# What's the best practice to avoid NPE against a collection field of a POJO/Java Bean?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, javabeans, pojo

Suppose I have a POJO/Java Bean class with a `Collection` field:

```
public class Foo{//original code 
  private List<Bar> barList;

  public List<Bar> getBarList(){
    return this.barList;
  }

  public void setBarList(List<Bar> barList){
    this.barList=barList;
  }
}
```

How to avoid NPE when `getBarList()` is called()? I mean `getBarList()` might return null and the caller would throw a NPE. Let's say I have to keep the setter and NULL have no semantic meaning here.

```
public class Foo{//modified code. 
  private List<Bar> barList = new ArrayList<Bar>();//1) default value since construct to avoid this.barList being null.

  public List<Bar> getBarList(){
    return this.barList;
  }

  public void setBarList(List<Bar> barList){
    //2.a) check and throw a NPE
    Objects.requireNonNull(barList);
    //2.b) replace the NULL value
    if(barList==null){
        this.barList.clear();//less cost then `this.barList = new ArrayList<Bar>();`
    }else{
        this.barList=barList;
    }        
  }
}
```

- Is it necessary of 1) for each collection field?
- Which one is better, either 2.a) or 2.b)? And why? Guava makes a choice of 2.a), like `FluentIterable.from(null)`, but it's not a POJO/Java Bean.
- Is there any best practice or principle for POJO/Java Bean to follow to avoid NPE? I think the modified code is no longer a POJO for some logical code in the setter.

Thanks!

Comment: 2 and 3 solve nothing, since you can't be sure the setter is called before the getter is called

Comment: @Stultuske 1) must have been executed before 2) or 3).

Comment: @Anderson i have removed my comment, but your statement is wrong. `this.barList` is different variable to `barList` and causes different behaviour of the setter method.

Comment: @Anderson wrong. In the setter, there's a significant difference between ``this.barList`` and ``barList``

Comment: `getBarList()` might return null, but will never throw a NPE!

Comment: @hinneLinks the point is, where it is called might, based on that null.

Comment: @Anderson drop the assert, by default they are not enabled in Java. If you really want to avoid all trouble: instantiate the List at instantiation of foo, and don't allow a setter to set a null value.

Comment: @f1sh I do know they're different between `this.barList` and `barList`. Please check the code again. First I make  `barList = new List<Bar>();`, So the argument `barList` will never be null. Then always `this.barList=barList` to make sure `this.barList` will never be null.

Comment: @Stultuske Please check the code again.`Assert` here is not the keyword of Java language but a static class as a tool or util.

Comment: To avoid NPE ... check for NULL before calling a method on that reference. If you want to **avoid the NULL-check** return NULL-Objects - in this case maybe an empty List (but not **the** empty List if it has to be mutable). And in Java 8 there is Optional ...

Comment: @Anderson and I'm supposed to know how that Assert class works (even whether it works with asserts or not) without seeing it's code, or even a mention of what class it actually is?

Comment: @Fildor Return NULL-Objects like an empty List is not efficient. If I never set a null value, it's not necessary to check it in the get method. `Optional` is not friendly with some tool based on reflection since it doesn't have a public constructor.

Comment: So that basically leaves you with Bohemian's answer: Set the list to an instance at creation and get rid of the setter.

Comment: @Fildor Sorry, I have to keep the setter since it's an existed class and too many references for me to modify all of them :(

Comment: Ok, but you can change it so "setting null" will result for example in list.clear() or something like that instead of nulling the reference. Of course again: That is only valid if the null return value is not relied upon somewhere.

Comment: @Fildor Good idea. I will update the code.

Comment: @Fildor It's not a perfect pattern. Consider `foo.setBarList(anImmuableList)` and then `foo.setBarList(null)`.

Comment: Is this a possible case? I think not since you stressed the fact you cannot have an immutable List because clients will mutate it.

Comment: @Fildor In my case it's not possible, but what about considering all above as a pattern?

Comment: I wouldn't consider all above as a pattern. There are many factors that make that design reasonable or useless. There is not one single "one-fits-all"-solution for avoiding NPEs at a client. Most of the time you are not in the lucky position to create a design from scratch and can apply patterns in the first place. Most often you have to "work with what you get". Which can include "cannot return immutable lists" or "clients rely on NULL for semantics" ...

Answer (score 2):

Initialize the field in the declaration. Note that your code doesn't compile - you can't instantiate `List`, try:

```
private List<Bar> barList = new ArrayList<Bar>();
```

Reasons are:

- Instantiating a list is pretty cheap
- It's the least code that gets the job done
- The big problem with lazy initialisation is thread safety - it requires special code

Comment: What if `setBarList(null)` would be called? He'd have to check for that then too, IMHO.

Comment: @Fil it would be better to delete the setter. It doesn't make sense, because other clients would expect that stuff they added would still be there

Comment: I agree. You should add this to your answer, though. I did not take it for granted.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my mistake of `ArrayList`, I've updated it. Let's say I have to keep the setter. What's more, Do you mean it's a best practice to delete the setter of a collection field?

Answer (score 2):

This Problem is not occurring in the setter, but the getter.

1) Might cause significant overhead because some `List` implementations have an initial size for the backing data container (such as `ArrayList`).

2) Makes no sense because you still get an Exception. It doesn't solve the problem.

3) is the correct approach, but not in the setter! Place this in the getter:

```
if(this.barList==null){
  this.barList = new LinkedList<Bar>();
}
```

Comment: I'd rather use `java.util.Collections.emptyList()` instead of creating a new List.

Comment: The problem isn't really in the getter, neither, it's at the place where the result of the getter may be used. who's to say 'null' is not valid?

Comment: @hinneLinks Why? That restricts you from manipulating the list.

Comment: you cannot call `new List<Bar>()` ... Also, lazy creation might impose concurrency issues.

Comment: @Fildor you're right, of course you need an implementation of ``List``. And yes, those issues are valid. Not in the scope of my answer though :D

Comment: @f1sh Something wrong when the caller do `foo.getBarList().add(aBar);` twice. The first `aBar` is missing.

Comment: @Anderson that cannot happen. I bet you still do in in the setter and overwrite the parameter value. I'll update the code.

Comment: @Anderson you probably have two instances of your class, or are creating a new one every time you use it (which replaces and discards the old one)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
private List<Bar> barList = new List<Bar>();
```

Generally speaking, when you have a getter method which returns a List it is better return empty list instead `null` value.

Comment: this will not compile. And I agree with Stultuske who would argue to use the term "better" here. Null may have a semantic meaning. So it is not always "better" to return an empty collection instead of null. Especially when changing legacy code, you could brake application logic that way.

Comment: @Fildor Yes, I'm dealing with some legacy code. And I'm sure in this case NULL have no semantic meaning. I should have told more context about it, and sorry for that again.

Answer (score 0):

You could special-case null and return an empty list instead.

```
public List<Bar> getBarList() {
    return barList != null ? barList : Collections.<Bar>emptyList();
}
```

or you could start the list empty

```
  private List<Bar> barList = Collections.<Bar>emptyList();
```

Comment: Isn't that emptyList immutable?

Comment: @Fildor - Yes - would that be a problem?

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon Sorry, immutable list could not be accepted, because the caller might execute`getBarList().add(aBar);`  Neither could be a mutable empty list in the getter for the same reason.

Comment: Or do you mean POJO must be immutable?